# HTTP request body to array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using js in a node environment with npm request.

I'm trying to grab Id from body.

Body:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 201801310058,
    "ItemType": 2,
    "SourceId": 2,
    "SourceUID": "4c45370f-a63d-4768-8772-03a7d7b364ff",
    "SourceName": null,
    "Duration": 16564,
    "Synchronized": false,
    "TimeStamp": "2018-01-31T18:01:03.7510329+01:00",
    "TrigValue": 0.0,
    "DataSize": 24766691,
    "Reindexed": false
  }
]
```

Without the square brackets it was easy using body["Id"].

What is the best practice in this case?

Edit:

Here's the whole code:

```
request('http://localhost:8124/Json/GetLastItems?sourceId=-1&numRecords=1&authToken=f3c6a605-7265-4a4d-922b-dd5c5f9966ee', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body[0].Id);
});
```

body[0].Id is undefined

Comment: Just `body[0].Id`.

Comment: Isn't `body` a string?  Don't you have to use `JSON.parse(body)` to get an object/array out of it?

Comment: @James that is correct. So I tried    var item = JSON.parse(body) and then item.Id. Still not working.

Comment: body represents an array, so it would still need to be item[0].id

Comment: Still nothing:    request('http://localhost:8124/Json/GetLastItems?sourceId=-1&numRecords=1&authToken=f3c6a605-7265-4a4d-922b-dd5c5f9966ee', function (error, response, body) {
        var item = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(item[0].Id);
    });

Answer (score 1):

Because the body here is and array, to get the `Id` property, you'd need to use `body[0].Id`.

But if there's ever a chance that there's more than one object in the array, to get each of the Ids, you'd have to loop over the body:

`for(let i = 0, l = body.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(body[i].Id); // gets the Id property of this specific object in body
}`

Comment: I'm still getting body[0].Id undefined. request('http://localhost:8124/Json/GetLastItems?sourceId=-1&numRecords=1&authToken=xxx', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body[0].Id);
    });

Answer (score 0):

it seem to be an array 
so you should use

```
body[0].Id
```